# Label polylines parallel but off line end

Tags: qgis, labeling, line

I can get polyline labels to appear parallel to the line but I'd really like to have them off the end of the line, not on the line. Is there a way of doing this with QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, go on the `Layer Properties` > `Labels` > `Placement` window.

Then, edit the expression for both X and Y coordinates, as in the image below:

[image]

In the expression field, use `x_at(0)` or `x_at(-1)` for setting the label at the start or at end of the features, respectively (do the same for the Y coordinate):

[image]

Finally, click on the `Apply` button and enjoy!

---

**EDIT**

If you see that some option has been overridden, you will still be able to set the desired output if you follow these two last steps (see the image below):

3) Edit the "Rotation" parameter in the same way as before, but use this expression:

```
90 + line_interpolate_angle( $geometry, 0)
```

4) Go again to the step 2 (only step 2, only for the X coordinate!) and edit the expression by adding an "offset" to your end point (it will depend on the measurement units). For example, if I set this expression:

```
$x_at( -1) + 5
```

I will obtain the result you see in the image (I think as expected).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this brilliant tip. Is there a similar expression to set the orientation of the label? With these expressions I get all the labels horizontal, but I really want them parallel to the polylines. Note: in the first section of the Placement tab which is titled Placement I have the Parallel radio button checked but this seems to be overridden by the data defined values. Thanks. (I'm using 2.12 Lyon. It may be this has been changed in later versions)

Comment: @simonc8 I edited my answer, now it should work. If it works also for you, please remember to accept my answer because it could be useful in the future for other users! =)

Comment: Thanks, @ndawson! It's a pleasure receiving your feedback =). However, I think I will edit my answer soon for a better explanation of the solution. At this moment, it's a bit difficult to clearly understand it.

Comment: @mgri Thanks for the additional functions - I had to update my QGIS to find the line_interpolate_angle function. However, I think the equation for rotation should be 90 - line_interpolation_angle($geometry,0) because the label angle increases anticlockwise while the line geometry angle increases clockwise. I am also experimenting with making the offsets more sophisticated to be applicable for lines at any orientation. This will involve a calculation using $scale, and also sin and cos of the line_interpolation_angle. I'll add a post when I've got it solved.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I performed the test on the line you see in the image, so I think you need to add more rules for a general case. However, I gave you an idea!